# конвертировать scrapy.Response в объект BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, scrapy, bs4

У меня есть полностью рабочий скрапер поисковой выдачи мобильного яндекса, написанный с помощью `bs4`. Теперь задача состоит в том, чтобы перебросить логику этого парсера в оболочку `scrapy`.

Как я могу конвертировать scrapy.Response в объект BeautifulSoup?
я уже перепробовал разные способы, но все мимо.

несколько вариантов кода ниже:

общая часть:

```
class YaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yandex_mobile"
    base_url = "https://m.yandex.ru/search/"
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
```

вариант 1:

```
def start_requests(self):
    from urllib.parse import quote

    input_list = ['кредитная карта','кредит']
    for i in input_list:
        yield scrapy.Request(self.base_url+'?text='+'{0}'.format(quote(i))+'&lr='+str(self.lr), callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):

    soup = self.BS(str(response), 'lxml')
    ...
    (further manipulations)
```

в варианте 1 вместо самой разметки HTML возвращается *страница с текстом собранной ссылки в теле самой страницы* в стиле:`<200 https://m.yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82&lr=213>`. Ну и ошибки в стиле ненайденных на странице элементов.

вариант 2:

```
def start_requests(self):
    from urllib.parse import quote

    input_list = ['кредитная карта','кредит']
        for i in input_list:
            yield self.urllib.request.urlopen(self.base_url+'?text='+'{0}'.format(quote(i))+'&lr='+str(self.lr))

def parse(self, response): 
    soup = self.BS(str(response), 'lxml')
    ...
    (further manipulations)
```

ошибка:

```
2017-07-10 18:15:50 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 58, in run
    self.crawler_process.start()
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 285, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1243, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1252, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 878, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/reactor.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._a, **self._kw)
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 135, in _next_request
    self.crawl(request, spider)
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 210, in crawl
    self.schedule(request, spider)
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 216, in schedule
    if not self.slot.scheduler.enqueue_request(request):
  File "/home/dfialkovskiy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 54, in enqueue_request
    if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request):
builtins.AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'dont_filter'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать пример [отсюда](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html),

> **Can I use Scrapy with BeautifulSoup?**
>
> Yes, you can. As mentioned above, BeautifulSoup can be used for parsing HTML responses in Scrapy
>   callbacks. You just have to feed the response’s body into a
>   BeautifulSoup object and extract whatever data you need from it.

В общем, код указанный ниже должен сработать:

```
# use lxml to get decent HTML parsing speed
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```